# JHipster project with 4.13.3 and Maven integration QueryDSL for querying JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, querydsl

When generating a JHipster project with 4.13.3, and doing a Maven integration of QueryDSL (like described in http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html_single/#d0e132), the Query types are not generated into target/generated-sources/java.

Before I used JHipster 4.10.x and it worked.

What changed? What I noticed with 4.13.3, that the pom.xml changed, for example the parent is not present any more, before it was:

```
    <parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Now with JHipster 4.13.3 this is missing. I also had to define in the properties of the pom.xml

```
        <querydsl.version>4.1.3</querydsl.version>
```

otherwise when doing a mvn clean install it throws an ERROR.

What to do to do a Maven integration of QueryDSL into a JHipster project with 4.13.3?

Cheers